# Where to store the configuration files of python applications on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I have a python program that must work on Windows and Linux. There are some configuration options I normally store in a file, in a subdirectory of the program's directory.

For Windows, I converted it to exe and created an Installer for it. And now I have the problem of dealing with the config file.

What is the best place to save the configuration file? I have read that for Windows `os.environ['APPDATA']+'myAppName'` is the path that must be used. Is it correct? Is it standard? Will it work in all versions of Windows at least from XP (and at least in English and Spanish)?

PD: I am not interested in using ConfigParser. Config file is in my own format and I have working code for reading/writing from it.

Comment: as you ask explicitly for windows stuff I've fixed the title for you. hope that's OK.

Comment: You should use `os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], 'myAppName')` to build the path

Comment: [os.path.expandvars](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars)('$APPDATA/myAppName')

Comment: Also see ["Where Should I Put Configuration Files?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160097/) over on SoftwareEngineering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Storing settings in the user directory is usually a good idea.

These days, you should probably use something like the [appdirs](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) library to find a good path to store your configuration in.

Under most Unices, just store a (preferably dot-prefixed) file in the home directory. Under OS X, you'd want to create a directory for your application in the user's Library folder, and store your files there. Under Windows, APPDATA is a good place to build a directory in for your application. It should work on all Windows localizations, and it looks like it was also available in Windows XP.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. So you said is it safe to use `APPDATA` no matter what version of Windows is used (XP, Vista, 7... 32bits, 64bits... English, Spanish)?

Comment: [Latest standards](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) seem to suggest to use a directory under `~/.local` to store application data.

Comment: @glglgl for application _data_, you are correct. But the OP is asking about for user-configurable application _settings_ , you should use `~/.config` if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set. If you're complying with the XDG Base Directory Specification, that is.

Answer (score 6):

## platformdirs

There is a better solution now ... better than speculating about what is best on each platform, better than environment variables which may or may not be defined, and even better than `appdirs`:  `platformdirs` ([GitHub](https://github.com/platformdirs/platformdirs), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) [Snyk](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/platformdirs)).

```
import platformdirs
appname = 'OurGreatApp'
print(f"User config files should be stored in {platformdirs.user_config_dir(appname)}")
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, it is common to store the configuration file in the users home directory, for instance `~/.myprogramrc`. On windows Vista and up, users have a home directory as well (/Users/username) and a would recommend storing your settings there in a subfolder (/Users/useranem/myprogram). Storing the settings in the application folder will generate UAC warnings.

On Windows XP, users do not have a home folder. Some programs make the choice of putting configuration in the 'My Documents' folder which I guess is as good a place as any.

Comment: On XP, there is a kind of home folder as well. It is the parent of the `My Documents` folder. But it is not advisable to sore something there; instead, the `APPDATA` method should be used.

Comment: thanks for your help. As Rodin said, UAC is a problem when writing files to "Program Files". @glglgl I don't have a XP machine to test, do you know what would be the path to `APPDATA` in this OS?

Comment: Here (WinXP, German version) it is `C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\myusername\Anwendungsdaten`, under an English one probably `C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Appdata` or similiar.

Comment: On XP there's an environment variable called `HOMEPATH` which contains the path to the current user's home folder.

Comment: As was said in a comment to the accepted answer, instead of using `~/.myprogramrc`, you should use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/myprogram/myprogramrc`, which commonly resolves to `~/.config/myprogram/myprogramrc`.